# Issue with gradle with adding Open JavaFX package from Maven Central

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx

So in my build.gradle file I have this  dependencies added.

```
dependencies {

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.6.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxb-impl
    compile group: 'javax.xml', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls
    compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: '11'


}
```

The class of other dependencies were added except for javafx classes. It wasn't downloaded all I get is just the meta-inf directory.
I am using JDK 11, so I really need openjfx repo to use JavaFX. because in JDK 11, javafx is decoupled.

Update: I am using Intellij Idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each supported platform has its own version of JavaFx module artifacts, so you need to specify it too:

```
compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: '11', classifier: 'linux' //'win', 'mac'
```

Additionally, you will need to explicitly add all transitive dependencies of the included javafx modules, because gradle cannot resolve platform specific modules by itself:

```
compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: '11', classifier: 'linux'
compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: '11', classifier: 'linux'
```

Check official documentation: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle

Comment: Thanks now its downloading the classes but I got a new error 
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Comment: If you've followed the guide (set classpath as module path, added modules) and you're running your application directly from gradle, then it should already work. But, if you're running from IDE and not from gradle, you'll need to download JavaFx SDK ([link](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)) and change VM Options in Run Configuration manually to: `--module-path="/path/to/javafx-sdk-11/lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls`

Comment: Now another error occured. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x555e2372) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x555e2372
 at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
 at com.flashery.herocafeserver.Main.<init>(Main.java:29)
 ... 13 more
Exception running application com.flashery.herocafeserver.Main

Comment: See this line "because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util"

Comment: I downloaded the JavaFX Windows SDK

Comment: You are using `FXML`, but you didn't include `javafx.fxml` module: `--add-modules=javafx.fxml,javafx.controls`.